# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. --> project:/contracts/"".sol:26:23: | 26 | function initialize() initializer public

Tags: smartcontracts, nft

When running npx truffle compile, i get the above error message.

I am trying to transition an NFT smart contract into upgradeable form and have imported the relevant source codes. It deploys to testnet fine, but when replacing the constructor with "function Initialize() initializer pubic {" i get the above error message.

Can someone help?

I also get an "Identifier not found or not unique" by my "mapping(address=>bool) private _operatorEnabled;

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract ERC721CarbonAsset is ERC721URIStorage, Pausable, AccessControl  {
  
  bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant BURNER_ROLE = keccak256("BURNER_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant OPERATOR_ROLE = keccak256("OPERATOR_ROLE");
  
  // Base URI
  string private _baseUri;
  address _forwarder;
  
  mapping(uint256 => string) private _digests;
  mapping(uint256 => string) private _infoRoots;
  
  // Addresses under operator control
  mapping(address => bool) private _operatorEnabled;
  
  
function initialize() initializer public {
  // constructor() public ERC721("", "") Pausable() { 
    _baseUri = "";
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(PAUSER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(BURNER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(OPERATOR_ROLE, msg.sender);
  }
  
  function pause() external onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
    _pause();
  }

  function unpause() external onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
    _unpause();
  }

  /**
   * @dev See {ERC20-_beforeTokenTransfer}.
   * Taken from ERC20Pausable
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - the contract must not be paused.
   */
  function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual override  {
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    require(!paused(), "ERC721Pausable: token transfer while paused");
  }
  
  function mint(address to, uint256 tokenId, string memory tokenUri, string memory digest) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
    _mint(to, tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenUri);
    _digests[tokenId] = digest;
  }

  function burn(uint256 tokenId) public onlyRole(BURNER_ROLE) {
    _burn(tokenId);
  }
  
  function setBaseURI(string memory uri) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) {
    _baseUri = uri;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Base URI for computing {tokenURI}. If set, the resulting URI for each
   * token will be the concatenation of the `baseURI` and the `tokenId`. Empty
   * by default, can be overriden in child contracts.
   */
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return _baseUri;
  }

  function infoRoot(uint256 tokenId) external view virtual returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI query for nonexistent token");

    string memory _infoRoot = _infoRoots[tokenId];

    // If there is no infoRoot set, return an empty string.
    if (bytes(_infoRoot).length == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    return _infoRoot;
  }

  function setInfoRoot(uint256 tokenId, string memory _infoRoot) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token");
    _infoRoots[tokenId] = _infoRoot;
  }
  
  function digest(uint256 tokenId) external view virtual returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI query for nonexistent token");

    string memory digest = _digests[tokenId];

    // If there is no digest set, return an empty string.
    if (bytes(digest).length == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    return digest;
  }
  
  function setDigest(uint256 tokenId, string memory digest) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token");
    _digests[tokenId] = digest;
  }

  // Operator initiatiated token transfer
  function operatorTransfer(address recipient, uint256 tokenId) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() returns (bool) {
    address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
    require(isOperatorControlled(owner), "ERC721: sender not under operator control");
    // Reset appoval
    _approve(msg.sender, tokenId);
    transferFrom(owner, recipient, tokenId);
    return true;
  }
  
  // Address owner can enable their address for operator control
  // Default state is operator disabled
  function enableOperatorControl() external whenNotPaused() returns (bool) {
    require(msgSender() != address(0), "ERC20: owner is a zero address");
    require(!isOperatorControlled(msgSender()), "ERC20: owner already under operator control");
    _operatorEnabled[msgSender()] = true;
    return true;
  }
  
  // Operator role can remove operator control from an address
  function disableOperatorControl(address owner) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() returns (bool) {
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner is a zero address");
    require(isOperatorControlled(owner), "ERC721: owner not under operator control");
    _operatorEnabled[owner] = false;
    return true;
  }
  
  function isOperatorControlled(address owner) public view returns (bool) {
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner is a zero address");
    return _operatorEnabled[owner];
  }

  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC721, AccessControl) returns (bool) {
      return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
  }

  function msgSender() internal view returns(address sender) {
    if(msg.sender == _forwarder) {
      bytes memory array = msg.data;
      uint256 index = msg.data.length;
      assembly {
          // Load the 32 bytes word from memory with the address on the lower 20 bytes, and mask those.
          sender := and(mload(add(array, index)), 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
      }
    } else {
        sender = msg.sender;
    }
    return sender;
  }

  function setForwarder(address forwarder) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) returns (bool) {
    _forwarder = forwarder;
    return true;
  }
  
  function getForwarder() external view returns (address) {
    return _forwarder;
  }
}
```

I tried to change the initializer function around a bit, inline with onlyInitializing functionality https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/releases/tag/v4.4.1

But that also returned a similar error regarding identifier not found or not unique

Answer (score 1):

There were a few problems with the code:

1. there needs to be a constructor function that sets the token name and symbol (inherited from ERC721 contract)
2. the initialize function should not also have the word "initializer" in the function declaration
3. The code will work if with just the above, but there are warnings regarding the overlapping of your function named "digest" with the name "digest" of various input parameters and variables defined within a few functions. Easiest way to solve this is to change the function name

updated code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract ERC721CarbonAsset is ERC721URIStorage, Pausable, AccessControl  {
  
  bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant BURNER_ROLE = keccak256("BURNER_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant OPERATOR_ROLE = keccak256("OPERATOR_ROLE");
  
  // Base URI
  string private _baseUri;
  address _forwarder;
  
  mapping(uint256 => string) private _digests;
  mapping(uint256 => string) private _infoRoots;
  
  // Addresses under operator control
  mapping(address => bool) private _operatorEnabled;

  constructor() ERC721("BasicNFT", "BNFT") {}
  
  
function initialize() public {
  // constructor() public ERC721("", "") Pausable() { 
    _baseUri = "";
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(PAUSER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(BURNER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(OPERATOR_ROLE, msg.sender);
  }
  
  function pause() external onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
    _pause();
  }

  function unpause() external onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
    _unpause();
  }

  /**
   * @dev See {ERC20-_beforeTokenTransfer}.
   * Taken from ERC20Pausable
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - the contract must not be paused.
   */
  function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual override  {
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    require(!paused(), "ERC721Pausable: token transfer while paused");
  }
  
  function mint(address to, uint256 tokenId, string memory tokenUri, string memory digest) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
    _mint(to, tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenUri);
    _digests[tokenId] = digest;
  }

  function burn(uint256 tokenId) public onlyRole(BURNER_ROLE) {
    _burn(tokenId);
  }
  
  function setBaseURI(string memory uri) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) {
    _baseUri = uri;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Base URI for computing {tokenURI}. If set, the resulting URI for each
   * token will be the concatenation of the `baseURI` and the `tokenId`. Empty
   * by default, can be overriden in child contracts.
   */
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return _baseUri;
  }

  function infoRoot(uint256 tokenId) external view virtual returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI query for nonexistent token");

    string memory _infoRoot = _infoRoots[tokenId];

    // If there is no infoRoot set, return an empty string.
    if (bytes(_infoRoot).length == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    return _infoRoot;
  }

  function setInfoRoot(uint256 tokenId, string memory _infoRoot) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token");
    _infoRoots[tokenId] = _infoRoot;
  }
  
  function digestDifferentName(uint256 tokenId) external view virtual returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI query for nonexistent token");

    string memory digest = _digests[tokenId];

    // If there is no digest set, return an empty string.
    if (bytes(digest).length == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    return digest;
  }
  
  function setDigest(uint256 tokenId, string memory digest) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token");
    _digests[tokenId] = digest;
  }

  // Operator initiatiated token transfer
  function operatorTransfer(address recipient, uint256 tokenId) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() returns (bool) {
    address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
    require(isOperatorControlled(owner), "ERC721: sender not under operator control");
    // Reset appoval
    _approve(msg.sender, tokenId);
    transferFrom(owner, recipient, tokenId);
    return true;
  }
  
  // Address owner can enable their address for operator control
  // Default state is operator disabled
  function enableOperatorControl() external whenNotPaused() returns (bool) {
    require(msgSender() != address(0), "ERC20: owner is a zero address");
    require(!isOperatorControlled(msgSender()), "ERC20: owner already under operator control");
    _operatorEnabled[msgSender()] = true;
    return true;
  }
  
  // Operator role can remove operator control from an address
  function disableOperatorControl(address owner) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() returns (bool) {
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner is a zero address");
    require(isOperatorControlled(owner), "ERC721: owner not under operator control");
    _operatorEnabled[owner] = false;
    return true;
  }
  
  function isOperatorControlled(address owner) public view returns (bool) {
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner is a zero address");
    return _operatorEnabled[owner];
  }

  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC721, AccessControl) returns (bool) {
      return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
  }

  function msgSender() internal view returns(address sender) {
    if(msg.sender == _forwarder) {
      bytes memory array = msg.data;
      uint256 index = msg.data.length;
      assembly {
          // Load the 32 bytes word from memory with the address on the lower 20 bytes, and mask those.
          sender := and(mload(add(array, index)), 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
      }
    } else {
        sender = msg.sender;
    }
    return sender;
  }

  function setForwarder(address forwarder) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) returns (bool) {
    _forwarder = forwarder;
    return true;
  }
  
  function getForwarder() external view returns (address) {
    return _forwarder;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have replied in the "answers" section my further comments regarding constructors...

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, upgradeable contracts cannot contain Constructors.

See https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/upgrading-smart-contracts

I have added `"@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";`

and inherited from this in the contract declaration, which now doesn't return the initial error message.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

abstract contract ERC721CarbonAsset is ERC721URIStorage, Pausable, AccessControl, Initializable  {
  
  bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant BURNER_ROLE = keccak256("BURNER_ROLE");
  bytes32 public constant OPERATOR_ROLE = keccak256("OPERATOR_ROLE");
  
  // Base URI
  string private _baseUri;
  address _forwarder;
  
  mapping(uint256 => string) private _digests;
  mapping(uint256 => string) private _infoRoots;
  
  // Addresses under operator control
  mapping(address => bool) private _operatorEnabled;
  
  
function initialize() initializer public {
  // constructor() public ERC721("", "") Pausable() { 
    _baseUri = "";
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(PAUSER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(BURNER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(OPERATOR_ROLE, msg.sender);
  }
  
  function pause() external onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
    _pause();
  }

  function unpause() external onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
    _unpause();
  }

  /**
   * @dev See {ERC20-_beforeTokenTransfer}.
   * Taken from ERC20Pausable
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - the contract must not be paused.
   */
  function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual override  {
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    require(!paused(), "ERC721Pausable: token transfer while paused");
  }
  
  function mint(address to, uint256 tokenId, string memory tokenUri, string memory digest) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
    _mint(to, tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenUri);
    _digests[tokenId] = digest;
  }

  function burn(uint256 tokenId) public onlyRole(BURNER_ROLE) {
    _burn(tokenId);
  }
  
  function setBaseURI(string memory uri) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) {
    _baseUri = uri;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Base URI for computing {tokenURI}. If set, the resulting URI for each
   * token will be the concatenation of the `baseURI` and the `tokenId`. Empty
   * by default, can be overriden in child contracts.
   */
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return _baseUri;
  }

  function infoRoot(uint256 tokenId) external view virtual returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI query for nonexistent token");

    string memory _infoRoot = _infoRoots[tokenId];

    // If there is no infoRoot set, return an empty string.
    if (bytes(_infoRoot).length == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    return _infoRoot;
  }

  function setInfoRoot(uint256 tokenId, string memory _infoRoot) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token");
    _infoRoots[tokenId] = _infoRoot;
  }
  
  function digest(uint256 tokenId) external view virtual returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI query for nonexistent token");

    string memory digest = _digests[tokenId];

    // If there is no digest set, return an empty string.
    if (bytes(digest).length == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    return digest;
  }
  
  function setDigest(uint256 tokenId, string memory digest) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token");
    _digests[tokenId] = digest;
  }

  // Operator initiatiated token transfer
  function operatorTransfer(address recipient, uint256 tokenId) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() returns (bool) {
    address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
    require(isOperatorControlled(owner), "ERC721: sender not under operator control");
    // Reset appoval
    _approve(msg.sender, tokenId);
    transferFrom(owner, recipient, tokenId);
    return true;
  }
  
  // Address owner can enable their address for operator control
  // Default state is operator disabled
  function enableOperatorControl() external whenNotPaused() returns (bool) {
    require(msgSender() != address(0), "ERC20: owner is a zero address");
    require(!isOperatorControlled(msgSender()), "ERC20: owner already under operator control");
    _operatorEnabled[msgSender()] = true;
    return true;
  }
  
  // Operator role can remove operator control from an address
  function disableOperatorControl(address owner) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) whenNotPaused() returns (bool) {
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner is a zero address");
    require(isOperatorControlled(owner), "ERC721: owner not under operator control");
    _operatorEnabled[owner] = false;
    return true;
  }
  
  function isOperatorControlled(address owner) public view returns (bool) {
    require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner is a zero address");
    return _operatorEnabled[owner];
  }

  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC721, AccessControl) returns (bool) {
      return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
  }

  function msgSender() internal view returns(address sender) {
    if(msg.sender == _forwarder) {
      bytes memory array = msg.data;
      uint256 index = msg.data.length;
      assembly {
          // Load the 32 bytes word from memory with the address on the lower 20 bytes, and mask those.
          sender := and(mload(add(array, index)), 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
      }
    } else {
        sender = msg.sender;
    }
    return sender;
  }

  function setForwarder(address forwarder) external onlyRole(OPERATOR_ROLE) returns (bool) {
    _forwarder = forwarder;
    return true;
  }
  
  function getForwarder() external view returns (address) {
    return _forwarder;
  }
}
```